# What would be a good way to visualize recent win/loss (player form) data?

Tags: info-visualisation, data, statistics

I have data like this which represents the recent form (win/loss record) of a player:

```
★★★☆★★☆★☆☆★★★★★★
```

Now, I want to visualize this data. What would be a good way to do so? The purpose is to develop a companion app for a game which shows all statistics of that game.

Now the important thing is that this data will gradually increase. The above data is only a sample. And also, assume that there will be no ties/no-results, etc.

I am thinking of a net win/loss line chart which goes up if you win and down if you lose. Would that be good?

Comment: If it's "recent" form it shouldn't increase, one game should really drop out, becoming non-recent, when the latest result is added no? In that sense, scale shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @mgraham it's not actually recent. but i mentioned recent just for the ideas of the visualization. it's slightly confusing but bear with me.... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to visualize just the total wins and losses any simple chart or table will do. If you want to visualize the progress throughout the season though, what you have is similar to Edward Tufte's [sparklines](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0001OR) visualizing wins and losses using simple icons.

[image]

The stars work ok, but it takes a bit more work to distinguish between wins and losses. Here Tufte uses spatial displacement, along with coloring win streaks red.

On the linked page Tufte also has several example time series graphs. They would work here as well, with the Y axis height being the net [wins - losses]. You could then have a guideline at 0 to show how far above/below losing a team is throughout the season.

Answer (score 0):

How about a use of trophies displaying the number of wins and losses?

[image]

Comment: well that would be good but the number of games will increase and so many trophies wouldn't fit in the display. such visualization won't be good I think. I want something like charts. Wait I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get something up and running quickly, include a win/loss percentage to quickly size up the competition.

[image: burn]